# Incompatible types error when assigning inheriting class to inherited interface

Tags: java, generics, gradle, gson

So I was looking into how to use the RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory from the gson extras branch and seem to have run into a peculiar issue. My IDE doesn't show that this is an error, however, when I compile the project I get error: incompatible types: RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory cannot be converted to TypeAdapterFactory. Is there a specific reason that I cannot assign to inherited class?

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        TypeAdapterFactory factory = new RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory<Number>()
    }
}

public final RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory<T> implements TypeAdapterFactory {}
```

**EDIT 1**

I have made the example more clear and the exact error is:
error: incompatible types: RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory cannot be converted to TypeAdapterFactory
        return factory;

It's also worth noting that I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.5 and Gradle 4.3.1.

Comment: What is your IDE

Comment: @janith1024 I'm using Jetbrains IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.5

Comment: try to rebuild project some times last build effect

Comment: @janith1024 Is there a compiler arg that I can use to have the compiler errors show fully qualified class names?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so moving some of the classes around I've determined that it's most likely an issue with gradle module configuration. Will have to look into that more, but I've essentially solved the problem by moving the class from one module to another.